# How can we display html page lying in assets?

Tags: android

my code is Here
java file

```
package org.example.webviewdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewDemo extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       webView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_compontent);
       webView.loadUrl("file://android_asset//faq.htm");
   }

}
```

xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >


<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webview_compontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1.0"   
/>
```

but i cant get page content
faq.htm is in folder assets

please helpme

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try a Project > Clean and rebuild

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/folderName/index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Uri.fromFile( File ), and get the file from getAssets().open(fileName)??